# group by 2 fields oracle sql inner join

Tags: group-by

I can't get the syntax correct to be able to group by two fields: as_of_date and ISSUERID.  Thanks!

```
select as_of_date, count(distinct(issuer_id)) from
crd_own.ml_corp_index_data_monthly  tb1
INNER JOIN pm_own.esg_credit_factors tb2 
ON tb1.TICKER = tb2.ISSUER_TICKER
AND trunc(tb1.DATADATE, 'month') = trunc(tb2.AS_OF_DATE, 'month')
where INDEXNAME ='IG' 
and DATADATE = '31-DEC-17'
group by as_of_date, ISSUERID
order by as_of_date asc
```

Comment: Posting a broken query without any explanation what's wrong will not help us help you.  What does "can't get the syntax correct" mean?  What's wrong with the query?  Error out?  No result?  Wrong result?  Where's the sample input?  Where's the expected output?  If you want answer, post proper information.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi ORA-00904: "ISSUERID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the same number of "non-aggregating" columns in both the `select` and `group by` clauses

```
SELECT
    as_of_date
  , COUNT( DISTINCT (issuer_id) )
...
GROUP BY
    as_of_date
  , ISSUERID     <<< this is the problem
```

You need to either include ISSUERID in the select clause:

```
SELECT
    as_of_date
  , ISSUERID
  , COUNT( DISTINCT (issuer_id) )
...
GROUP BY
    as_of_date
  , ISSUERID
ORDER BY
    as_of_date ASC
```

Or remove ISSUERID completely.

---

```
SELECT
               -- non-aggregating columns
    as_of_date
  , ISSUERID

              -- aggregating columns
  , COUNT( DISTINCT (issuer_id) )

FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY
              -- repeat all non-aggregating columns here
    as_of_date
  , ISSUERID
```